# Best way of debugging this: cannot open shared object file

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, linker, autotools

ALL,

I am trying to see what the problem I have. I am compiling my program and the library under Gentoo Linux with Anjuta + gcc-5.3 under C++11.

The compilation and linking completed successfully. But when running I am getting the error in subject.

My best guess would be that I'm missing some dependency when linking. Or I need to link libA, libB, but linking libB, libA - unfortunately I'm not very familiar with Linux build system, I'm relying on Anjuta IDE to do the right thing and Anjuta still wants some operations to be performed manually.

Is there a way to check that?

Thank you.

[EDIT]

I tried re-building and re-installing. Here is the output:

This is from the build directory:

```
igor@IgorDellGentoo ~/dbhandler/Debug/libdialogs/.libs $ pwd
/home/igor/dbhandler/Debug/libdialogs/.libs
igor@IgorDellGentoo ~/dbhandler/Debug/libdialogs/.libs $ ldd libdialogs.so.0
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc9cf32000)
        libsqlite_lib.so.0 => /home/igor/dbhandler/Debug/libsqlite/.libs/libsqlite_lib.so.0 (0x00007fa53c52d000)
        libfieldswindow.so.0 => /home/igor/dbhandler/Debug/libfieldswindow/.libs/libfieldswindow.so.0 (0x00007fa53c316000)
        libshapeframework.so.0 => /home/igor/dbhandler/Debug/libshapeframework/.libs/libshapeframework.so.0 (0x00007fa53bfee000)
        libwx_gtk2u_xrc-3.1.so.0 => /home/igor/wxWidgets/buildGTK/lib/libwx_gtk2u_xrc-3.1.so.0 (0x00007fa53bce4000)
        libwx_gtk2u_html-3.1.so.0 => /home/igor/wxWidgets/buildGTK/lib/libwx_gtk2u_html-3.1.so.0 (0x00007fa53b9f4000)
        libwx_gtk2u_qa-3.1.so.0 => /home/igor/wxWidgets/buildGTK/lib/libwx_gtk2u_qa-3.1.so.0 (0x00007fa53b7c6000)
        libwx_gtk2u_adv-3.1.so.0 => /home/igor/wxWidgets/buildGTK/lib/libwx_gtk2u_adv-3.1.so.0 (0x00007fa53b39b000)
        libwx_gtk2u_core-3.1.so.0 => /home/igor/wxWidgets/buildGTK/lib/libwx_gtk2u_core-3.1.so.0 (0x00007fa53ab38000)
        libwx_baseu_xml-3.1.so.0 => /home/igor/wxWidgets/buildGTK/lib/libwx_baseu_xml-3.1.so.0 (0x00007fa53a923000)
        libwx_baseu_net-3.1.so.0 => /home/igor/wxWidgets/buildGTK/lib/libwx_baseu_net-3.1.so.0 (0x00007fa53a6dc000)
        libwx_baseu-3.1.so.0 => /home/igor/wxWidgets/buildGTK/lib/libwx_baseu-3.1.so.0 (0x00007fa53a281000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/5.4.0/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fa539e5e000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007fa539b5d000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fa5397c5000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/5.4.0/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fa5395ae000)
        libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fa538f67000)
        libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fa538cb1000)
        libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 (0x00007fa538aa4000)
        libatk-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libatk-1.0.so.0 (0x00007fa53887d000)
        libcairo.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libcairo.so.2 (0x00007fa53855b000)
        libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fa538338000)
        libgio-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libgio-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fa537fb6000)
        libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 (0x00007fa537da0000)
        libpango-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libpango-1.0.so.0 (0x00007fa537b54000)
        libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fa5378ff000)
        libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libfontconfig.so.1 (0x00007fa5376c2000)
        libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007fa53741b000)
        libgthread-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libgthread-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fa537218000)
        libglib-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fa536ede000)
        libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libX11.so.6 (0x00007fa536b9f000)
        libXxf86vm.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libXxf86vm.so.1 (0x00007fa536998000)
        libSM.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libSM.so.6 (0x00007fa536790000)
        libnotify.so.4 => /usr/lib64/libnotify.so.4 (0x00007fa536588000)
        libpng16.so.16 => /usr/lib64/libpng16.so.16 (0x00007fa536352000)
        libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007fa53613c000)
        libjpeg.so.62 => /usr/lib64/libjpeg.so.62 (0x00007fa535ee4000)
        libtiff.so.5 => /usr/lib64/libtiff.so.5 (0x00007fa535c6f000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fa535a6b000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fa535850000)
        libexpat.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007fa535625000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00005624e7aa5000)
        libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fa535420000)
        libXfixes.so.3 => /usr/lib64/libXfixes.so.3 (0x00007fa53521a000)
        libXrender.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libXrender.so.1 (0x00007fa53500f000)
        libXinerama.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libXinerama.so.1 (0x00007fa534e0c000)
        libXi.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libXi.so.6 (0x00007fa534bfc000)
        libXrandr.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libXrandr.so.2 (0x00007fa5349f0000)
        libXcursor.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libXcursor.so.1 (0x00007fa5347e5000)
        libXcomposite.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libXcomposite.so.1 (0x00007fa5345e2000)
        libXdamage.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libXdamage.so.1 (0x00007fa5343de000)
        libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libXext.so.6 (0x00007fa5341cc000)
        libpixman-1.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libpixman-1.so.0 (0x00007fa533f21000)
        libEGL.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libEGL.so.1 (0x00007fa533cfe000)
        libxcb-shm.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libxcb-shm.so.0 (0x00007fa533afa000)
        libxcb-render.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libxcb-render.so.0 (0x00007fa5338ef000)
        libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007fa5336cc000)
        libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libGL.so.1 (0x00007fa533434000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007fa53322c000)
        libresolv.so.2 => /lib64/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007fa533015000)
        libharfbuzz.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libharfbuzz.so.0 (0x00007fa532daf000)
        libffi.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libffi.so.6 (0x00007fa532ba7000)
        libbz2.so.1 => /lib64/libbz2.so.1 (0x00007fa532996000)
        libICE.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libICE.so.6 (0x00007fa53277a000)
        libuuid.so.1 => /lib64/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007fa532575000)
        libX11-xcb.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libX11-xcb.so.1 (0x00007fa532372000)
        libxcb-dri2.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libxcb-dri2.so.0 (0x00007fa53216d000)
        libxcb-xfixes.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libxcb-xfixes.so.0 (0x00007fa531f65000)
        libxcb-shape.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libxcb-shape.so.0 (0x00007fa531d60000)
        libgbm.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libgbm.so.1 (0x00007fa531b54000)
        libdrm.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libdrm.so.2 (0x00007fa531945000)
        libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libXau.so.6 (0x00007fa531740000)
        libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007fa53153a000)
        libglapi.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libglapi.so.0 (0x00007fa53130c000)
        libxcb-glx.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libxcb-glx.so.0 (0x00007fa5310f1000)
        libxcb-dri3.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libxcb-dri3.so.0 (0x00007fa530eee000)
        libxcb-present.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libxcb-present.so.0 (0x00007fa530ceb000)
        libxcb-randr.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libxcb-randr.so.0 (0x00007fa530adc000)
        libxcb-sync.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libxcb-sync.so.1 (0x00007fa5308d5000)
        libxshmfence.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libxshmfence.so.1 (0x00007fa5306d2000)
        libgraphite2.so.3 => /usr/lib64/libgraphite2.so.3 (0x00007fa5304a4000)
```

This is from the install directory:

```
IgorDellGentoo lib # pwd
/usr/local/lib
IgorDellGentoo lib # ldd libdialogs.so.0
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd9375d000)
        libsqlite_lib.so.0 => /usr/local/lib/libsqlite_lib.so.0 (0x00007f8802369000)
        libfieldswindow.so.0 => not found
        libshapeframework.so.0 => /usr/local/lib/libshapeframework.so.0 (0x00007f8802040000)
        libwx_gtk2u_xrc-3.1.so.0 => /home/igor/wxWidgets/buildGTK/lib/libwx_gtk2u_xrc-3.1.so.0 (0x00007f8801d36000)
        libwx_gtk2u_html-3.1.so.0 => /home/igor/wxWidgets/buildGTK/lib/libwx_gtk2u_html-3.1.so.0 (0x00007f8801a46000)
        libwx_gtk2u_qa-3.1.so.0 => /home/igor/wxWidgets/buildGTK/lib/libwx_gtk2u_qa-3.1.so.0 (0x00007f8801818000)
        libwx_gtk2u_adv-3.1.so.0 => /home/igor/wxWidgets/buildGTK/lib/libwx_gtk2u_adv-3.1.so.0 (0x00007f88013ed000)
        libwx_gtk2u_core-3.1.so.0 => /home/igor/wxWidgets/buildGTK/lib/libwx_gtk2u_core-3.1.so.0 (0x00007f8800b8a000)
        libwx_baseu_xml-3.1.so.0 => /home/igor/wxWidgets/buildGTK/lib/libwx_baseu_xml-3.1.so.0 (0x00007f8800975000)
        libwx_baseu_net-3.1.so.0 => /home/igor/wxWidgets/buildGTK/lib/libwx_baseu_net-3.1.so.0 (0x00007f880072e000)
        libwx_baseu-3.1.so.0 => /home/igor/wxWidgets/buildGTK/lib/libwx_baseu-3.1.so.0 (0x00007f88002d3000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/5.4.0/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f87ffedb000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f87ffbda000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f87ff842000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/5.4.0/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f87ff62b000)
        libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f87fefe5000)
        libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f87fed2e000)
        libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f87feb21000)
        libatk-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libatk-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f87fe8fb000)
        libcairo.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libcairo.so.2 (0x00007f87fe5d8000)
        libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f87fe3b5000)
        libgio-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libgio-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f87fe034000)
        libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f87fde1d000)
        libpango-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libpango-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f87fdbd1000)
        libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f87fd97d000)
        libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libfontconfig.so.1 (0x00007f87fd73f000)
        libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007f87fd498000)
        libgthread-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libgthread-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f87fd296000)
        libglib-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f87fcf5b000)
        libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f87fcc1c000)
        libXxf86vm.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libXxf86vm.so.1 (0x00007f87fca16000)
        libSM.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libSM.so.6 (0x00007f87fc80d000)
        libnotify.so.4 => /usr/lib64/libnotify.so.4 (0x00007f87fc605000)
        libpng16.so.16 => /usr/lib64/libpng16.so.16 (0x00007f87fc3d0000)
        libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007f87fc1b9000)
        libjpeg.so.62 => /usr/lib64/libjpeg.so.62 (0x00007f87fbf61000)
        libtiff.so.5 => /usr/lib64/libtiff.so.5 (0x00007f87fbced000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f87fbae8000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f87fb8cd000)
        libexpat.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f87fb6a2000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055d400ce6000)
        libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f87fb49d000)
        libXfixes.so.3 => /usr/lib64/libXfixes.so.3 (0x00007f87fb297000)
        libXrender.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libXrender.so.1 (0x00007f87fb08d000)
        libXinerama.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libXinerama.so.1 (0x00007f87fae89000)
        libXi.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libXi.so.6 (0x00007f87fac79000)
        libXrandr.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libXrandr.so.2 (0x00007f87faa6e000)
        libXcursor.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libXcursor.so.1 (0x00007f87fa862000)
        libXcomposite.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libXcomposite.so.1 (0x00007f87fa65f000)
        libXdamage.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libXdamage.so.1 (0x00007f87fa45c000)
        libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libXext.so.6 (0x00007f87fa249000)
        libpixman-1.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libpixman-1.so.0 (0x00007f87f9f9f000)
        libEGL.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libEGL.so.1 (0x00007f87f9d7b000)
        libxcb-shm.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libxcb-shm.so.0 (0x00007f87f9b77000)
        libxcb-render.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libxcb-render.so.0 (0x00007f87f996d000)
        libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f87f9749000)
        libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libGL.so.1 (0x00007f87f94b1000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007f87f92aa000)
        libresolv.so.2 => /lib64/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f87f9092000)
        libharfbuzz.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libharfbuzz.so.0 (0x00007f87f8e2d000)
        libffi.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libffi.so.6 (0x00007f87f8c24000)
        libbz2.so.1 => /lib64/libbz2.so.1 (0x00007f87f8a14000)
        libICE.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libICE.so.6 (0x00007f87f87f7000)
        libuuid.so.1 => /lib64/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007f87f85f2000)
        libX11-xcb.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libX11-xcb.so.1 (0x00007f87f83ef000)
        libxcb-dri2.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libxcb-dri2.so.0 (0x00007f87f81ea000)
        libxcb-xfixes.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libxcb-xfixes.so.0 (0x00007f87f7fe2000)
        libxcb-shape.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libxcb-shape.so.0 (0x00007f87f7ddd000)
        libgbm.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libgbm.so.1 (0x00007f87f7bd1000)
        libdrm.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libdrm.so.2 (0x00007f87f79c2000)
        libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f87f77bd000)
        libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f87f75b7000)
        libglapi.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libglapi.so.0 (0x00007f87f7389000)
        libxcb-glx.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libxcb-glx.so.0 (0x00007f87f716e000)
        libxcb-dri3.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libxcb-dri3.so.0 (0x00007f87f6f6b000)
        libxcb-present.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libxcb-present.so.0 (0x00007f87f6d68000)
        libxcb-randr.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libxcb-randr.so.0 (0x00007f87f6b59000)
        libxcb-sync.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libxcb-sync.so.1 (0x00007f87f6952000)
        libxshmfence.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libxshmfence.so.1 (0x00007f87f674f000)
        libgraphite2.so.3 => /usr/lib64/libgraphite2.so.3 (0x00007f87f6521000)
```

Also, relevant part of the install log:

```
Making install in libfieldswindow
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/igor/dbhandler/Debug/libfieldswindow'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/igor/dbhandler/Debug/libfieldswindow'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/lib'
 /bin/sh ../libtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c   libfieldswindow.la '/usr/local/lib'
libtool: warning: relinking 'libfieldswindow.la'
libtool: install: (cd /home/igor/dbhandler/Debug/libfieldswindow; /bin/sh "/home/igor/dbhandler/Debug/libtool"  --tag CXX --mode=relink g++ -I../../libshapeframework -I/home/igor/wxWidgets/buildGTK/lib/wx/include/gtk2-unicode-3.1 -I/home/igor/wxWidgets/include -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DWXUSINGDLL -D__WXGTK__ -pthread -g -O0 -std=c++11 -L../libshapeframework -lshapeframework -L/home/igor/wxWidgets/buildGTK/lib -pthread -Wl,-rpath,/home/igor/wxWidgets/buildGTK/lib -lwx_gtk2u_xrc-3.1 -lwx_gtk2u_html-3.1 -lwx_gtk2u_qa-3.1 -lwx_gtk2u_adv-3.1 -lwx_gtk2u_core-3.1 -lwx_baseu_xml-3.1 -lwx_baseu_net-3.1 -lwx_baseu-3.1 -o libfieldswindow.la -rpath /usr/local/lib libfieldswindow_la-field.lo libfieldswindow_la-fieldswindow.lo libfieldswindow_la-fieldwindow.lo )
libtool: relink: g++  -fPIC -DPIC -shared -nostdlib /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../../../lib64/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/5.4.0/crtbeginS.o  .libs/libfieldswindow_la-field.o .libs/libfieldswindow_la-fieldswindow.o .libs/libfieldswindow_la-fieldwindow.o   -L../libshapeframework -L/usr/local/lib -lshapeframework -L/home/igor/wxWidgets/buildGTK/lib -lwx_gtk2u_xrc-3.1 -lwx_gtk2u_html-3.1 -lwx_gtk2u_qa-3.1 -lwx_gtk2u_adv-3.1 -lwx_gtk2u_core-3.1 -lwx_baseu_xml-3.1 -lwx_baseu_net-3.1 -lwx_baseu-3.1 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/5.4.0 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../../../lib64 -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../.. -lstdc++ -lm -lc -lgcc_s /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/5.4.0/crtendS.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../../../lib64/crtn.o  -pthread -g -O0 -pthread -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/home/igor/wxWidgets/buildGTK/lib   -pthread -Wl,-soname -Wl,libfieldswindow.so.0 -o .libs/libfieldswindow.so.0.0.0
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libfieldswindow.so.0.0.0T /usr/local/lib/libfieldswindow.so.0.0.0
libtool: install: (cd /usr/local/lib && { ln -s -f libfieldswindow.so.0.0.0 libfieldswindow.so.0 || { rm -f libfieldswindow.so.0 && ln -s libfieldswindow.so.0.0.0 libfieldswindow.so.0; }; })
libtool: install: (cd /usr/local/lib && { ln -s -f libfieldswindow.so.0.0.0 libfieldswindow.so || { rm -f libfieldswindow.so && ln -s libfieldswindow.so.0.0.0 libfieldswindow.so; }; })
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libfieldswindow.lai /usr/local/lib/libfieldswindow.la
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libfieldswindow.a /usr/local/lib/libfieldswindow.a
libtool: install: chmod 644 /usr/local/lib/libfieldswindow.a
libtool: install: ranlib /usr/local/lib/libfieldswindow.a
libtool: finish: PATH="/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin" ldconfig -n /usr/local/lib
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Libraries have been installed in:
   /usr/local/lib

If you ever happen to want to link against installed libraries
in a given directory, LIBDIR, you must either use libtool, and
specify the full pathname of the library, or use the '-LLIBDIR'
flag during linking and do at least one of the following:
   - add LIBDIR to the 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH' environment variable
     during execution
   - add LIBDIR to the 'LD_RUN_PATH' environment variable
     during linking
   - use the '-Wl,-rpath -Wl,LIBDIR' linker flag
   - have your system administrator add LIBDIR to '/etc/ld.so.conf'

See any operating system documentation about shared libraries for
more information, such as the ld(1) and ld.so(8) manual pages.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'install-data-am'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/igor/dbhandler/Debug/libfieldswindow'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/igor/dbhandler/Debug/libfieldswindow'
Making install in libdialogs
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/igor/dbhandler/Debug/libdialogs'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/igor/dbhandler/Debug/libdialogs'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/lib'
 /bin/sh ../libtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c   libdialogs.la '/usr/local/lib'
libtool: warning: relinking 'libdialogs.la'
libtool: install: (cd /home/igor/dbhandler/Debug/libdialogs; /bin/sh "/home/igor/dbhandler/Debug/libtool"  --tag CXX --mode=relink g++ -I../../dbinterface -I../../libfieldswindow -I../../libshapeframework -I/home/igor/wxWidgets/buildGTK/lib/wx/include/gtk2-unicode-3.1 -I/home/igor/wxWidgets/include -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DWXUSINGDLL -D__WXGTK__ -pthread -g -O0 -std=c++11 -L../libsqlite -L../libshapeframework/ -L../dbinterface -L../libfieldswindow -ldbinterface -lsqlite_lib -lshapeframework -lfieldswindow -L/home/igor/wxWidgets/buildGTK/lib -pthread -Wl,-rpath,/home/igor/wxWidgets/buildGTK/lib -lwx_gtk2u_xrc-3.1 -lwx_gtk2u_html-3.1 -lwx_gtk2u_qa-3.1 -lwx_gtk2u_adv-3.1 -lwx_gtk2u_core-3.1 -lwx_baseu_xml-3.1 -lwx_baseu_net-3.1 -lwx_baseu-3.1 -o libdialogs.la -rpath /usr/local/lib libdialogs_la-databasetype.lo libdialogs_la-dialogs.lo libdialogs_la-odbcconfigure.lo libdialogs_la-selecttables.lo libdialogs_la-createindex.lo )
libtool: relink: g++  -fPIC -DPIC -shared -nostdlib /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../../../lib64/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/5.4.0/crtbeginS.o  .libs/libdialogs_la-databasetype.o .libs/libdialogs_la-dialogs.o .libs/libdialogs_la-odbcconfigure.o .libs/libdialogs_la-selecttables.o .libs/libdialogs_la-createindex.o   -L/home/igor/dbhandler/Debug/libshapeframework/.libs -L../libsqlite -L../libshapeframework/ -L../dbinterface -L../libfieldswindow -L/usr/local/lib -lsqlite_lib -ldbinterface -L/home/igor/wxWidgets/buildGTK/lib -lfieldswindow -L../libshapeframework -lshapeframework -lwx_gtk2u_xrc-3.1 -lwx_gtk2u_html-3.1 -lwx_gtk2u_qa-3.1 -lwx_gtk2u_adv-3.1 -lwx_gtk2u_core-3.1 -lwx_baseu_xml-3.1 -lwx_baseu_net-3.1 -lwx_baseu-3.1 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/5.4.0 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../../../lib64 -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../.. -lstdc++ -lm -lc -lgcc_s /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/5.4.0/crtendS.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../../../lib64/crtn.o  -pthread -g -O0 -pthread -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/home/igor/wxWidgets/buildGTK/lib   -pthread -Wl,-soname -Wl,libdialogs.so.0 -o .libs/libdialogs.so.0.0.0
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libdialogs.so.0.0.0T /usr/local/lib/libdialogs.so.0.0.0
libtool: install: (cd /usr/local/lib && { ln -s -f libdialogs.so.0.0.0 libdialogs.so.0 || { rm -f libdialogs.so.0 && ln -s libdialogs.so.0.0.0 libdialogs.so.0; }; })
libtool: install: (cd /usr/local/lib && { ln -s -f libdialogs.so.0.0.0 libdialogs.so || { rm -f libdialogs.so && ln -s libdialogs.so.0.0.0 libdialogs.so; }; })
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libdialogs.lai /usr/local/lib/libdialogs.la
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libdialogs.a /usr/local/lib/libdialogs.a
libtool: install: chmod 644 /usr/local/lib/libdialogs.a
libtool: install: ranlib /usr/local/lib/libdialogs.a
libtool: finish: PATH="/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin" ldconfig -n /usr/local/lib
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Libraries have been installed in:
   /usr/local/lib

If you ever happen to want to link against installed libraries
in a given directory, LIBDIR, you must either use libtool, and
specify the full pathname of the library, or use the '-LLIBDIR'
flag during linking and do at least one of the following:
   - add LIBDIR to the 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH' environment variable
     during execution
   - add LIBDIR to the 'LD_RUN_PATH' environment variable
     during linking
   - use the '-Wl,-rpath -Wl,LIBDIR' linker flag
   - have your system administrator add LIBDIR to '/etc/ld.so.conf'

See any operating system documentation about shared libraries for
more information, such as the ld(1) and ld.so(8) manual pages.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'install-data-am'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/igor/dbhandler/Debug/libdialogs'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/igor/dbhandler/Debug/libdialogs'
```

It looks like during the "make install" libdialogs.so.0 looses the dependency.

Any idea on what to do? Is it an error in the Makefile generation for libdialogs?

And here is the libdialogs->Properties->Linker options in Anjuta:

```
-L../libsqlite -L../libshapeframework/ -L../dbinterface -L../libfieldswindow -ldbinterface -lsqlite_lib -lshapeframework -lfieldswindow `/home/igor/wxWidgets/buildGTK/wx-config --libs`
```

[/EDIT]

[EDIT2]

```
igor@IgorDellGentoo ~/dbhandler $ grep -ri "mode=relink" *
Debug/libdbwindow/libdbwindow.la:relink_command="(cd /home/igor/dbhandler/Debug/libdbwindow; /bin/sh \"/home/igor/dbhandler/Debug/libtool\"  --silent --tag CXX --mode=relink g++ -I../../libshapeframework -I../../dbinterface -I/home/igor/wxWidgets/buildGTK/lib/wx/include/gtk2-unicode-3.1 -I/home/igor/wxWidgets/include -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DWXUSINGDLL -D__WXGTK__ -pthread -g -O0 -std=c++11 -L../libshapeframework -L../libfieldswindow -lfieldswindow -lshapeframework -L/home/igor/wxWidgets/buildGTK/lib -pthread -Wl,-rpath,/home/igor/wxWidgets/buildGTK/lib -lwx_gtk2u_xrc-3.1 -lwx_gtk2u_html-3.1 -lwx_gtk2u_qa-3.1 -lwx_gtk2u_adv-3.1 -lwx_gtk2u_core-3.1 -lwx_baseu_xml-3.1 -lwx_baseu_net-3.1 -lwx_baseu-3.1 -o libdbwindow.la -rpath /usr/local/lib libdbwindow_la-ErdForeignKey.lo libdbwindow_la-ErdTable.lo libdbwindow_la-NArrow.lo libdbwindow_la-OneArrow.lo libdbwindow_la-column.lo libdbwindow_la-constraint.lo libdbwindow_la-table.lo libdbwindow_la-GUIDatabaseTable.lo libdbwindow_la-databasecanvas.lo libdbwindow_la-databasedoc.lo libdbwindow_la-databaseview.lo libdbwindow_la-dbview.lo libdbwindow_la-MyErdTable.lo libdbwindow_la-ErdLineShape.lo @inst_prefix_dir@)"
Debug/libtool:      relink_command="(cd `pwd`; $SHELL \"$progpath\" $preserve_args --mode=relink $libtool_args @inst_prefix_dir@)"
Debug/libfieldswindow/libfieldswindow.la:relink_command="(cd /home/igor/dbhandler/Debug/libfieldswindow; /bin/sh \"/home/igor/dbhandler/Debug/libtool\"  --silent --tag CXX --mode=relink g++ -I../../libshapeframework -I/home/igor/wxWidgets/buildGTK/lib/wx/include/gtk2-unicode-3.1 -I/home/igor/wxWidgets/include -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DWXUSINGDLL -D__WXGTK__ -pthread -g -O0 -std=c++11 -L../libshapeframework -lshapeframework -L/home/igor/wxWidgets/buildGTK/lib -pthread -Wl,-rpath,/home/igor/wxWidgets/buildGTK/lib -lwx_gtk2u_xrc-3.1 -lwx_gtk2u_html-3.1 -lwx_gtk2u_qa-3.1 -lwx_gtk2u_adv-3.1 -lwx_gtk2u_core-3.1 -lwx_baseu_xml-3.1 -lwx_baseu_net-3.1 -lwx_baseu-3.1 -o libfieldswindow.la -rpath /usr/local/lib libfieldswindow_la-field.lo libfieldswindow_la-fieldswindow.lo libfieldswindow_la-fieldwindow.lo @inst_prefix_dir@)"
Debug/libdialogs/libdialogs.la:relink_command="(cd /home/igor/dbhandler/Debug/libdialogs; /bin/sh \"/home/igor/dbhandler/Debug/libtool\"  --silent --tag CXX --mode=relink g++ -I../../dbinterface -I../../libfieldswindow -I../../libshapeframework -I/home/igor/wxWidgets/buildGTK/lib/wx/include/gtk2-unicode-3.1 -I/home/igor/wxWidgets/include -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DWXUSINGDLL -D__WXGTK__ -pthread -g -O0 -std=c++11 -L../libsqlite -L../libshapeframework/ -L../dbinterface -L../libfieldswindow -ldbinterface -lsqlite_lib -lshapeframework -lfieldswindow -L/home/igor/wxWidgets/buildGTK/lib -pthread -Wl,-rpath,/home/igor/wxWidgets/buildGTK/lib -lwx_gtk2u_xrc-3.1 -lwx_gtk2u_html-3.1 -lwx_gtk2u_qa-3.1 -lwx_gtk2u_adv-3.1 -lwx_gtk2u_core-3.1 -lwx_baseu_xml-3.1 -lwx_baseu_net-3.1 -lwx_baseu-3.1 -o libdialogs.la -rpath /usr/local/lib libdialogs_la-databasetype.lo libdialogs_la-dialogs.lo libdialogs_la-odbcconfigure.lo libdialogs_la-selecttables.lo libdialogs_la-createindex.lo @inst_prefix_dir@)"
Debug/libdbloader/libdbloader.la:relink_command="(cd /home/igor/dbhandler/Debug/libdbloader; /bin/sh \"/home/igor/dbhandler/Debug/libtool\"  --silent --tag CXX --mode=relink g++ -I/usr/include -I../../dbinterface -I../../libsqlite -I../../libodbc -I/home/igor/wxWidgets/buildGTK/lib/wx/include/gtk2-unicode-3.1 -I/home/igor/wxWidgets/include -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DWXUSINGDLL -D__WXGTK__ -pthread -g -O0 -std=c++11 -L../libsqlite -L../libodbc -L/home/igor/wxWidgets/buildGTK/lib -pthread -Wl,-rpath,/home/igor/wxWidgets/buildGTK/lib -lwx_gtk2u_xrc-3.1 -lwx_gtk2u_html-3.1 -lwx_gtk2u_qa-3.1 -lwx_gtk2u_adv-3.1 -lwx_gtk2u_core-3.1 -lwx_baseu_xml-3.1 -lwx_baseu_net-3.1 -lwx_baseu-3.1 -lsqlite_lib -lodbc_lib -o libdbloader.la -rpath /usr/local/lib libdbloader_la-dbloader.lo @inst_prefix_dir@)"
ltmain.sh:      relink_command="(cd `pwd`; $SHELL \"$progpath\" $preserve_args --mode=relink $libtool_args @inst_prefix_dir@)"
```

So the only place where the "relink"is referenced is a file in the Debug/ directory. Now the question is: where this file is generated from?

Since Anjuta is using autotools, I think that if I change the file that is parent to the Debug/libdialogs/libdialogs.la everything will be fine.

[/EDIT2]

Thank you.

Comment: did you try `ldd ./your_program`

Comment: Can you paste what exactly the error is?

Comment: @tristan, I updated the post with the relevant output. Thx.

Comment: @codegrep_admin, I can't as this a run-time error in the GUI. But it's just that - "cannot open shared object file libfieldswindow.so.0: no such file or directory"

Comment: @tristan, of course I don't run the so file. I'm trying to load it and run the exported function from it. Can you help?

Comment: i'm not familiar with Anjuta and from your description i could not find anything that leads to the problem.

Comment: @tristan, In the ldd output there is no dependency on the libfieldswindow.so after "make install". In the "make install" output forlibdialogs.so it calls "libtool: relink:" and this command does not contain linking to libfieldswindow.so. Do you know where the relinking is coming from? Please check the output I posted.

Comment: @tristan, more information added. Could you please take a look? It is not really about Anjuta - this IDE is using Autotools and friends. So if I fix generation of a Makefile and that file I just added then everything will be just fine.

Comment: @Igor what program fails to run with the failure?  can you run ldd on the program instead of the library?

Comment: @tristan, the program doesn't fail to run. the trouble is that when I try to load libdialogs it fails because it can't find libfieldswindow. However I think I make the order on relinking right, but still running ldd on the libdialogs fails. So At this point I don't know what to do. Also, just curious - why gcc linker doesn't error out if the library can't be found. But that's a topic for another question.

Comment: @Igor I'm confused...  you cannot run the program if it fails to link a shared library.  Anyway, you can use `LD_DEBUG` to debug how the linker fails. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html

Comment: @tristan, The executable binary does not depend on libdialogs.so. It is loaded in my code with dlopen().

Comment: @tristan, I added relevant output of "LD_DEBUG=all" to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40796255/what-is-wrong-with-dynamic-linking. However it is weird since "make install" should set the search path appropriately.

Comment: does /usr/local/lib/libfieldswindows.so.0 exist? Or did you add  /home/igor/dbhandler/Debug/libfieldswindow/.libs/ to your LD_LIBRARY_PATH ?

Comment: @arved, yes, the library does exist in /usr/local/lib. The LD_LIBRARY_PATH update should be done by the last command of "make install" please check the code in my post. [quote]libtool: finish: PATH="/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin" ldconfig -n /usr/local/lib[/quote].